# Error using AngulaJS and SimpleModal jQuery plugin together

Tags: angularjs, simplemodal

I'm trying to open a modal using SimpleModal OSX, and the values for some of the attributes are assigned using AngularJS. However, when I click an item to open a new modal it doesn't work and the page reloads. Here's the code to make this clear

```
<li ng-repeat="news in newsItems" class="some class">
   <a class="osx" href="#" data-page={{news.dataPageUrl}}>
      <article>
         <header>
            <span class="itemtype">{{news.dateHeader}}</span>
               <h1>{{news.header}}</h1>
         </header>
         <img height="145" src={{news.imageUrl}} alt={{news.imageHeader}} />
      </article>
   </a>
</li>
```

The dynamic items appear in my page, so the ng-repeat directive works. I added a static item and it opens a new modal without issues. The osx.js script is loaded at the end of the body tag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the href='#' as you don't really need that? Also, are you using a directive to open the model or just using classes?

Comment: Have you tried writing a directive? Because your inside an ng-repeat, it might be that the simplemodal osx code isn't binding the click event to those elements, simply because it hasn't been rendered. Having a directive will ensure the click event can call into SimpleModal.